# How to lock rotation in z of my camera while rotating the camera by using mobile gyroscope input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

I am rotating the camera in unity using gyroscope input, because
I want the player to look around the x,y. 
However somehow there is also rotation in z.
How do I keep the z rotation at 0, while at least remaining the smooth rotation in x and y I have now?

Have been googling but haven't found any solutions which actually keep the
z at 0.

Here is the code I use for rotation, it's attached to the camera.

```
 private void Start()
{
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    Input.gyro.enabled = true;
}

 private void Update()
{
    float gyro_In_x = -Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.x;
    float gyro_In_y = -Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.y;

    transform.Rotate(gyro_In_x, gyro_In_y, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the problem comes from the `transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(gyro_In_x, gyro_In_y, 0);` line. Trying setting the rotation value instead of multiplying it:

```
private void Start()
{
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    Input.gyro.enabled = true;
}

private void Update()
{
    Vector3 previousEulerAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
    Vector3 gyroInput = -Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased; //Not sure about the minus symbol (untested)

    Vector3 targetEulerAngles = previousEulerAngles + gyroInput * Time.deltaTime * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    targetEulerAngles.z = 0.0f;

    transform.eulerAngles = targetEulerAngles;

    //You should also be able do it in one line if you want:
    //transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x - Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.x * Time.deltaTime * Mathf.Rad2Deg, transform.eulerAngles.y - Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.y * Time.deltaTime * Mathf.Rad2Deg, 0.0f);
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Sorry just noticed I used the wrong code in update. The minus symbols are based on me slightly following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ugE1HQPA9g

Comment: Well I think using `Rotate()` may also introduce unwanted rotation on Z axis (could be wrong) : did my solution (manipulating `Transform.eulerAngles` directly) solve your problem ?

Comment: Yeah, thanks this works! 
I use this code instead it does the same, but is much shorter and clearer to me, incase anyone would like to know. 

        float gyro_In_x = -Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.x;
        float gyro_In_y = -Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.y;

        transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(gyro_In_x, gyro_In_y,  0.0f);

Comment: Well glad it helped! Keep in mind that when programming, pre-made tools are useful but you have to understand what is implied when using them (here the `Rotate` method): this is why I always prefer using something I'm sure about (like manually editing `Transform.eulerAngles`) when not certain about how a given method works :)