# Unity - Gyroscope - Rotation Around One Axis Only

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, quaternions, gyroscope

I'm using Unity to make a game that uses the Gyroscope. I am trying to detect the rotation of the device around the axis that goes through the screen, I'm assuming it's the Z-axis in Unity Space. I tried using `Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles.z` but it doesn't stay constant when tilting the device around the other axes, I want it to stay constant so that only the "Z-axis" determines the rotation of a car's steering wheel, for example. How can I implement this?

**EDIT:**
I tried doing something else. I used `Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased` instead of `Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles`

Here's the code:

```
    Vector3 gInput = Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased;
    gyroEuler += gInput * Time.deltaTime * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    float rollAngle = gyroEuler.z;

    while (rollAngle < 0)
    {
        rollAngle += 360;
    }
    while (rollAngle > 360)
    {
        rollAngle -= 360;
    }
```

But `gyroEuler` will be set to `(0, 0, 0)` regardless of the devices orientation at the start of the game so the device orientation will not be known in the beginning and also `Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased` is very inaccurate. I want to rotate the screen the way many games, like *Temple Run 2*, do but I want to be able to rotate it 360 degrees and get that angle of rotation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lock rotation in z of my camera while rotating the camera by using mobile gyroscope input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818719/how-to-lock-rotation-in-z-of-my-camera-while-rotating-the-camera-by-using-mobile)

Comment: No that one didn't help me much.

Comment: For example you don't need to estimate the "euler angle" , but you can simply estimate angle between transformed Axis (by current rotation) and for example ground plane. 
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/30/Plane_with_ENU_embedded_axes.svg/220px-Plane_with_ENU_embedded_axes.svg.png

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the right one. Else, do you have further problems with this? _(Accepting an answer helps future visitors coming on this page)_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I just tried it and it works well :

```
private void Start()
{
    Input.gyro.enabled = true;
}

private void Update()
{
    Vector3 previousEulerAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
    Vector3 gyroInput = -Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased;

    Vector3 targetEulerAngles = previousEulerAngles + gyroInput * Time.deltaTime * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    targetEulerAngles.x = 0.0f; // Only this line has been added
    targetEulerAngles.z = 0.0f;

    transform.eulerAngles = targetEulerAngles;

    //You should also be able do it in one line if you want:
    //transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, transform.eulerAngles.y - Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased.y * Time.deltaTime * Mathf.Rad2Deg, 0.0f);
}
```

What you need to do is create a central **Transform** (or use your player) and parent your **Camera** as child of it. Then set the **Camera** z-distance, height and angle to adjust your view. Finally attach the above script to the central **Transform**: rotating it will make your **Camera** move around following an arc.

**EDIT:** If you want to use `Input.gyro.attitude` instead you can do it as follow

```
private Vector3 startEulerAngles;
private Vector3 startGyroAttitudeToEuler;

private void Start()
{
    Input.gyro.enabled = true;
    startEulerAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
    startGyroAttitudeToEuler = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles;
}

private void Update()
{
    Vector3 deltaEulerAngles = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles - startGyroAttitudeToEuler;
    deltaEulerAngles.x = 0.0f;
    deltaEulerAngles.z = 0.0f;

    transform.eulerAngles = startEulerAngles - deltaEulerAngles;
}

public void ResetGyro()
{
    startGyroAttitudeToEuler = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I guess what you are looking for will be something like [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1265974/finding-physical-world-xyz-with-respect-to-an-ios.html): you can then check `upVec.y` and `upVec.x` for your Down/Up and Left/Right axis.

First create an empty **GameObject** that will be used as a dummy containing gyroscope rotation and set it in `phoneDummy` field of the script.

```
public Transform phoneDummy;

private void Start()
{
    Input.gyro.enabled = true;
}

private void Update()
{
    Vector3 gyroEuler = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles;
    phoneDummy.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(-1.0f * gyroEuler.x, -1.0f * gyroEuler.y, gyroEuler.z);

    Vector3 upVec = phoneDummy.transform.InverseTransformDirection(-1f * Vector3.forward);
}
```

`upVec.y` will be your ***pitch*** and `upVec.x` will be your ***roll*** axis.
(check [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Flight_dynamics_with_text.png) for axis reference)

But keep in mind values from `Input.gyro` are far from flawless: you may want to use `Input.compass.magneticHeading` if you are looking for a more persistent value (but of course less precise one).

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: Well it works fine but it doesn't calculate the angle accurately. I want it to measure the rotation angle of the screen so I was thinking of using Input.gyro.attitude but I don't know how to use it, I don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: @MoazAshraf Edited my post with a usage of `Input.gyro.attitude` but you will get some side-effects from using it (as orientation changing ~180° when tilting device back and forth around its vertical position).

Comment: Well this is exactly what I meant when I said I want rotation to be constant. How can I remove the side effect should have been my question.

Comment: Why is it when I rotate the device around the vertical axis, the Z reading changes?

Comment: Not sure about why the Z reading changes, however the `Input.compass.magneticHeading` value get +/-180° when you get past vertical orientation because the magnetic heading works with device being held horizontally: so it compensate when you move around "extrem angles" values (being device X angle = +/-90°).

Comment: Here's what I want to achieve: The user will hold the device any orientation they want, I want to get the angle of rotation around the axis that is perpendicular to the screen/passes through the screen (Like a Local Z-axis in unity). So when the user lays the phone horizontally on a desk, this axis should be vertical, if the user has the holds the device with the screen facing them, the axis should be in the forward direction of the user. I thought the gyroscope's attitude.eulerAngles.z gets this axis but apparently it reads real world axis, or at least that's what I think.

Comment: I edited my answer again with something I found online: agreed that Unity `Input.gyro.attitude` is quite a pain in the *** to work with. I don't understand why then didn't made it so it uses the same axis as the engine...

Comment: Thanks it helped tremendously! I logged the upVec to the screen and it is the vector that I'm looking for. All I need to do now is to get the phoneDummy's rotation around it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134516/discussion-between-moaz-ashraf-and-kardux).

Comment: Can you share how you solved this? I'm interested in the solution but the chat link is broken; not sure how to access the remaining info.  Thanks!

Comment: Well discussion didn't continued in chat finally :) The answer is pretty much what I gave in the Edit part. If you need further help considering this subject, don't hesitate to ask a new question and notify me about it: I'd gladly try yto give you an answer !

Comment: Thanks Kardux, I'm not sure how to notify you, here's my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935419/how-to-enable-gyroscope-camera-at-current-device-orientation

Comment: Hi @Valerie I saw your question but Programmer was faster (he/she always is) ;) Glad your problem has been solved !

Answer (score 1):

```
Gyroscope jyro;
private void Start()
{
    jyro = Input.gyro;
    jyro.enabled = true;
}

void Update()
{
    if (SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope)
    {
        transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, 0, -Input.gyro.attitude.z, Input.gyro.attitude.w);
    }
}
```

Took me ages, but you just need to use two of the quaternion values