# Gyroscope with compass help needed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions, gyroscope

I need to have a game object point north AND I want to combine this with gyro.attitude input.  I have tried, unsuccessfully, to do this in one step.  That is, I couldn't make any gyro script, which I found on the net, work with the additional requirement of always pointing north.  Trust me, I have tried every script I could find on the subject.  I deduced that it's impossible and probably was stupid to think it could be done; at least not this way (i.e. all-in-one).  I guess you could say I surmised that you can't do two things at once.  Then I thought possibly I could get the same effect by  breaking-up the duties.  That is, a game object that always points north via the Y axis.  Great, got that done like this:

`_parentDummyRotationObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(_parentDummyRotationObject.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 360 - Input.compass.trueHeading, 0), Time.deltaTime * 5f);`

And with the game object pointing north on the Y, I wanted to add the second game-object, a camera in this case, with rotation using gyro input on the X and Z axis.  The reason I have to eliminate the Y axes on the camera is because I get double rotation.  With two things rotating at once (i.e. camera and game-object), a 180 degree rotation yielded 360 in the scene.  Remember I need the game object to always point north (IRL) based on the device compass.  If my device is pointing towards the East, then my game-object would be rotated 90 degrees in the unity scene as it points (rotation) towards the north.

I have read a lot about gyro camera controllers and one thing I see mentioned a lot is you  shouldn't try to do this (limit it) on just 1 or 2 axis, when using Quaternions it's impossible when you don't know what you're doing, which I clearly do not.

I have tried all 3 solutions from this solved question: [Unity - Gyroscope - Rotation Around One Axis Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927052/unity-gyroscope-rotation-around-one-axis-only) and each has failed to rotate my camera on 1 axis to satisfy my rotational needs.  Figured I'd try getting 1 axis working before muddying the waters with the 2nd axis.  BTW, my requirements are simply that the camera should only rotate on 1 axis (in any orientation) based on the X axis of my device.  If I could solve for X, then I thought it'd be great to get Z gyro input to control the camera as well.  So far I cannot get the camera controlled on just 1 axis (X). Anyway, here are my findings...

The first solution, which used Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased, was totally inaccurate.  That is, if I rotated my device around a few times and then put my phone/device down on my desk, the camera would be in a different rotation/location each time.  There was no consistency.  Here's my code for the first attempt/solution:

```
<code>
private void Update()
{
  Vector3 previousEulerAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
  Vector3 gyroInput = Input.gyro.rotationRateUnbiased;
  Vector3 targetEulerAngles = previousEulerAngles + gyroInput * Time.deltaTime * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
  targetEulerAngles.y = 0.0f; 
  targetEulerAngles.z = 0.0f;
  transform.eulerAngles = targetEulerAngles;
}
</code>
```

The second solution was very consistent in that I could rotate my device around and then put it down on the desk and the unity camera always ended up in the same location/rotation/state so-to-speak.  The problem I had was the camera would rotate on the one axis (X in this case), but it did so when I rotated my device on either the y or x axis.  Either type of rotation/movement of my phone caused the unity camera to move on the  X.  I don't understand why the y rotation of my phone caused the camera to rotate on X.  Here is my code for solution #2:

```
    private void Start()
{
  Input.gyro.enabled = true;
  startEulerAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
  startGyroAttitudeToEuler = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles;
}
private void Update()
{
  Vector3 deltaEulerAngles = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles - startGyroAttitudeToEuler;
  deltaEulerAngles.y = 0.0f;
  deltaEulerAngles.z = 0.0f;
  transform.eulerAngles = startEulerAngles - deltaEulerAngles;
}
```

The 3rd solution:  I wasn't sure how to complete this last solution, so it never really worked.  With the 2 axis zeroed-out, the camera just flipped from facing left to right and back, or top to bottom and back; depending on which axis were commented out.  If none of the axis were commented-out (like the original solution) the camera would gyro around on all axis.  Here's my code for attempt #3:

```
    private void Start()
{
  _upVec = Vector3.zero;
  Input.gyro.enabled = true;
  startEulerAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
}
private void Update()
{
  Vector3 gyroEuler = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles;
  phoneDummy.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(-1.0f * gyroEuler.x, -1.0f * gyroEuler.y, gyroEuler.z);
  _upVec = phoneDummy.transform.InverseTransformDirection(-1f * Vector3.forward);
  _upVec.z = 0;
//    _upVec.x = 0;
  _upVec.y = 0;
  transform.LookAt(_upVec);
//    transform.eulerAngles = _upVec;
}
```

Originally I thought it was my skills, but after spending a month on this I'm beginning to think that this is impossible to do.  But that just can't be.  I know it's a lot to absorb, but it's such a simple concept.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Thought I'd add my hierarchy:

CameraRotator (parent with script) -> MainCamera (child)

CompassRotator (parent) -> Compass (child with script which rotates parent)

Comment: I got some of these but not others. 1.You want a gameobject to be facing north. 2.You want to combine this with gyro.attitude input...Why do you want to do #2? Is this 2D or 3D object?

Comment: This is a 3D augmented reality application so I use the device camera with the gyro to add "life" to the Unity scene/objects.  The current version I have has a 3d Compass rotating on the Y-axis.  The other 2 axis are 0, so the compass doesn't "float" in the scene like I want.  It's very stiff as it just rotates on y (to maintain northern direction/pointing).  Thanks

Comment: See [this](http://peted.azurewebsites.net/windows-phone-mobile-vr-gyro-head-tracking-in-unity3d/) post. The HeadTrack example may give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Programmer, that's actually an example I haven't seen before; which is shocking considering how much searching I've done.  Just goes to show ya.  Will let you know...

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in the following way:
Camara with default 0, 0, 0 rotation
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pd8f.png)

Object placed at the center of the default position of the camera.

Script for the Camera:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    Camera m_MainCamera;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Disable the sleep timeout during gameplay. 
        // You can re-enable the timeout when menu screens are displayed as necessary. 
        Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
        // Enable the gyroscope. 
        if (SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope)
        {
            Input.gyro.enabled = true;
        }
        m_MainCamera = Camera.main;
        m_MainCamera.enabled = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (m_MainCamera.enabled)
        {
            // First - Grab the Gyro's orientation. 
            Quaternion tAttitude = Input.gyro.attitude;
            // The Device uses a 'left-hand' orientation, we need to transform it to 'right-hand'
            Quaternion tGyro = new Quaternion(tAttitude.x, tAttitude.y, -tAttitude.z, -tAttitude.w);

            // the gyro attitude is tilted towards the floor and upside-down reletive to what we want in unity.  
            // First Rotate the orientation up 90deg on the X Axis, then 180Deg on the Z to flip it right-side up. 
            Quaternion tRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-90f, 0, 0) * tGyro;
            tRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 180f) * tRotation;

            // You can now apply this rotation to any unity camera!
            m_MainCamera.transform.localRotation = tRotation;
        }
    }
}
```

With this script my Object always face SOUTH no matter what.

If you want the object to face NORTH you just have to turn the view 180º on the Y axis as a last rotation:

```
Quaternion tRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-90f, 0, 0) * tGyro;
tRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 180f) * tRotation;
//Face NORTH:
tRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,180f, 0) * tRotation;
```

Hope this might help ;)